# Orbital of Hydrogen molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, molecules, hydrogen

does anybody here know an analytical approximation of the bonding hydrogen orbital MOLECULE?

I am looking for a good approximation to this orbital, that might be in some textbooks to get an impression how this whole concept of bonding antibonding works?

Comment: What do you mean by "bonding hydrogen orbital MOLECULE"? If this question has not been clarified, it is hard to answer "a good approximation to this orbital" (i.e., to what orbital?)

Answer (score 6):

The approximation that we all started out learning is the [linear combination of atomic orbitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination_of_atomic_orbitals) (LCAO) approach. The molecular wavefunction, $\Psi$, can be expressed as a sum of some set of basis functions:

$$ \Psi(\vec{r}) = \sum_n f_n(\vec{r}) $$

and a convenient set of basis functions is the atomic orbitals of hydrogen. As a starting point we could take just the two $1s$ orbitals of the hydrogen atoms, $\psi_a$ and $\psi_b$, and write the lowest energy molecular orbital as:

$$ \Psi \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \psi_a + \psi_b \right) $$

This gives you the bonding orbital, and the anti-bonding orbital is the difference of the atomic orbitals:

$$ \Psi^* \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \psi_a - \psi_b \right) $$

The approximation is too crude to be of use in comparing calculations with experiment, but it's a good way to play with the ideas involved. You'll find many articles on the web explaining how to calculate the energies of these orbitals. A quick Google found [this one](http://xbeams.chem.yale.edu/~batista/vvv/node31.html), which looks a good introduction, or you'll find a description in any introductory QM textbook. My copy of [Atkins Molecular Quantum Mechanics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Molecular-Quantum-Mechanics-Peter-Atkins/dp/0199541426) treats the LCAO calculation for hydrogen in chapter 9 (though I think it's chapter 8 in the latest edition).